# rerendering Template Tags in Dart

Tags: dart, polymer, polymer-1.0, dart-polymer

I have been all over their github, their website, as well as other sites.

The closest answer I can see is related entirely within PolymerJs, which was in another stack overflow thread.

```
var template = document.querySelector('template'); // Use specific selector here
template.iterator_.updateIteratedValue(); // Force Polymer to refresh template
```

but when I looked up the TemplateElement class, i did not see any sort of redraw methods, or signuatures which jumped out at me.

Ideally i have something like this:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{days}}">
  <div>{{item.name}}</div?
</template>
```

but when I change `days`, maybe adding another element to it, or deleting from it, it doesnt rerender the template.  What i was doing was as simple as:

```
List newArray = [];
set("days", newArray);
```

or something like:

```
set("days", days.map((Map m){ m['times'] = sampleTest.split(''); return m;}).toList());
```

Comment: I have trouble understanding what the question is about. What is the `template` tag you are querying in the first code block and how is it related to the `<template is="dom-repeat" ...>`?

Comment: i was shorthanding the code.   It would have an id set to something, which also has an id in the little markup sample I have.

Answer (score 0):

For adding a new element to the list that will trigger refresh on dom-repeat, use

```
add("days", day);
```

where day is the new element to be added onto the list.

For removing an element from the list that will trigger refresh on dom-repeat, use

```
removeAt("days", i);
```

where i is the index of the item on the list.

Alternatively, call removeAt() in a loop to remove everything and then call set("days", list), where list MUST be a new instance of List.